# Issues while generating the R file

Tags: android

I have some issues while generating the R file in android. I have two packages in my src folder com.mydomain and net.mydomain. Now only the net.mydomain.R file is generated not com.mydomain.R file as a result. the java files in my com.mydomain cannot access the ids like R.id R.layout. It is only populating for net.mydomain. So how can I generate com.mydomain.R file as well. Thanks

Comment: you should never get more than one R class unless you are referencing external library projects, is this your case?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the package you're using is the same that is in the manifest, check the line package, for example, in your case the package is com.mydomain, so:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mydomain"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Why not adding the net.mydomain like, com.mydomain.net?, using that way, you can solve your issue.